# make circle shape in the background of a container

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-animations

I am trying to build my first calculator can anyone explain to me why the green circle doesn't display on the background like the red and orange ones.

Code:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Quicksand:wght@300;400;500&display=swap');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  /* font-weight: 400; */
  /* font-size: 62.5%; */
}

body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient( 189.7deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) -10.7%, rgba(53, 92, 125, 1) 90.8%);
}

body::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: linear-gradient(#b91372 10%, #6b0f1a 90%);
  clip-path: circle(18% at 28% 34%);
}

body::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolut;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" />
  <title>Calculator By B-4C</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="ball-1"></div>
    <div class="ball-2"></div>
    <form class="calculator" name="calc">
      <div class="screen">
        <input type="text" name="txt" id="value" />
        <div class="previous-operand"></div>
        <div class="current-operand"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="num" onclick="document.calc.txt.value"></span>
    </form>
  </div>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Uyws.png)

I am trying to create a design where a green circle appears in the background behind a red and an orange circle. I have attempted to use the z-index property in CSS to achieve this, but it does not seem to be working as expected.

Comment: looks like css is not complete here, can edit the question with complete code, try to create snippet or share jsfiddle link

Comment: [how to create a runnable snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/2518285)

Comment: here is the jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/usefbk/y3dhu8Lq/#&togetherjs=LPcwzjfbjE

Answer (score 0):

You have green ball i.e. `.ball-1` inside `.container` which has `overflow: hidden` property, which is hiding the ball.

To fix this, move `<div class="ball-1"></div>` outside of `<div class="container">`

here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MadanBhandari/dgco8bak/1/).

Comment: sure, no problem :) mark the answer as accepted to show appreciation :) and good luck with your project

Answer (score 0):

It may solve your problem.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Quicksand:wght@300;400;500&display=swap');


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(189.7deg,
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) -10.7%,
      rgba(53, 92, 125, 1) 90.8%);
}

body::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: linear-gradient(#b91372 10%, #6b0f1a 90%);
  clip-path: circle(18% at 28% 34%);
}

body::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: linear-gradient(#ec9f05 10%, #ff4e00 100%);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  clip-path: circle(14% at 70% 80%);
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  border-radius: 12px;
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
  backdrop-filter: blur(25px);
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  z-index: 5;
}

.ball-1 {
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(#d4fc79 0%, #259d35 100%);
  transform: translate(159px, -90px);
  box-shadow: -15px 17px 17px rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.025);
  backdrop-filter: blur(25px);
  z-index: -5;
}

.container .calculator {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  max-width: 100vw;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 75px);
  grid-template-rows: minmax(120px, auto) repeat(5, 100px);
  background: transparent;
}

#value {
  grid-column: span 4;
  grid-row: span 4;
  height: 140px;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: right;
  outline: none;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  background: transparent;
}

.calculator>button {
  font-size: 3.2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.03);
  color: white;
  transition: 0.25s;
  outline: none;
}


.calculator>button:hover {
  transition: 0s;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.06);
}

.calculator>button:active {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="ball-1"></div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="ball-2"></div>
  <form class="calculator" name="calc">
    <div class="screen">
      <input type="text" name="txt" id="value" />
      <div class="previous-operand"></div>
      <div class="current-operand"></div>
    </div>
    <span class="num" onclick="document.calc.txt.value"></span>
  </form>
</div>
```